# expressjs is not returning any response to html

Tags: express

while submitting a form **without using ajax** I could see "message sent successfully" in my http://localhost/ss (working fine as it should)

But while submitting a form **using ajax $.post()** response is not receiving to $.post() method. I couldn't find any reason..

**Please note:** same code works fine with php

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#buttons").click(function() {
        $.post("http://localhost:3000/ss", {
          sendemail: $("#email").val(),
          sendname: $("#UserName").val(),
          sendpass: $("#Password").val()
        }, function(res) {
          alert(res);
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

  <body>

    <div class="forms">
      <form>
        <div class="formdiv">
          <label>User Email</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="formdiv">
          <label>User Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName" />
        </div>
        <div class="formdiv">
          <label>User Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" />
        </div>
      </form>
      <div style="background:green;padding:15px;" id="buttons">send</div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

parse.js

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

app.listen(3000, function(req, res)
{
  console.log("express is listening to port 3000");
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", function(req, res)
{
  res.send("hai");
});

app.post("/ss", function(req, res)
{
  var ss = req.body.sendemail;
  if (ss != undefined)
  {
    console.log(ss);
    res.send("message sent successfully");
  }
  else
  {
    res.send("error occurred");
  }
});
```

console prints user's email address "**The only problem is response to html**"

Comment: If I understand correct  alert(res) on the client returns undefined? Or never executes?

Comment: even if you replace alert(res) by alert("hai'); its not working.. which I mean "never executes" @slowdeath

Comment: could you try replacing res.send with res.end("a message")?

Comment: I tried just now, It's not working @slowdeath007

Comment: That's odd. Do you have morgan installed so you can see if the post ends successfully with code 200? Also you can try using the function $.ajax and not the shorthand function $.post

Comment: Are you running html from file directory, or from domain used by the server? If answer for the first question is "yes", then you probably are missing *CORS* support. Open your browser's console and see the response.

Comment: Thank you @slowdeath007,@Patryk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code looks okey by itself, although there's one issue, with (i suspect) the way you use it. You're not allowing for `cross-origin sharing`. In other words, if you'd try to run this code on another domain, you'd receive a **CORS** error, as server refuses to respond to the client.

Therefore, I suspect you're loading the .html file either:

- As local, html file.
- Are running it from different domain

both of those would (and are) returning mentioned above error. That's why you're not receiving the response, so you're not seeing the alert message.

In order to bypass the issue, you can either:

- Enable CORS support
- Render HTML file through the server (so request will be coming from the same domain).

Example here:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");

...

app.get("/", function(req, res)
{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.post("/signup", function(req, res)
{
  var email = req.body.email;

  if (!email)
  {
    return res.json({
        message: "error occurred"
    });
  }

  res.json({
    success: true;
  });
});
```